# trigger jquery events to dynamically load contents on change in value of hidden input type

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am working on triggering an event on change in the value of a hidden input type field. I will have to use the "on" as I am dynamically loading some content after the function call. Can anyone help with this? I have tried working around but it after the ajax call the events stop to trigger.

Comment: can you show some code what you have tried? And make maybe a [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: persons.loadFilters= function(event){
 
 var selectId=document.getElementById("personTypeId").value;
 if(selectId==1||selectId==4||selectId==8){
 $("#directoryFilter").load("directory/filters #directoryFilter",{"selectId":selectId});  
  }
 
};

Comment: the above is the portion of code im using. I manually triggered the onchange event on the hidden field. But after the load function call the jquery events stop working.

Comment: @aldanux the js file is too long so i only pasted the corresponding part to the problem

Answer (score 1):

Hard to say without seeing some more code, but if the hidden field is somewhere inside #directoryFilter, you're most likely using .on incorrectly.

Instead of:

```
$(hidden_input_selector).on('change', fn);
```

use:

```
$('#directoryFilter').on('change', hidden_input_selector, fn);
```

Comment: i tried the above solution. it still does not trigger the events after ajax call